# Python/Django sorting a queryset by distance in REST framework

Tags: python, django

Currently, I am adding a field, 'distance', to a queryset after it's been created, and then returning it. However, I would like to sort the queryset by distance, if it's possible to annotate it.

Currently, my model, GeoCache, has fields latitude and longitude as models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=10, null=True, blank=True). Using geopy, I can add distance to my queryset like this:

```
user_location = (self.request.GET.get('latitude') , self.request.GET.get('longitude'))
geocache_list = GeoCache.objects.all()
for geocache in geocache_list:
    geocache.distance = geodesic(user_location, (geocache.latitude, geocache.longitude)).miles
return geocache_list
```

However, I would like to sort the queryset by distance, from lowest to greatest. However, when I try to annotate the search as such:

```
geocache_list = GeoCache.objects.all().annotate(distance=geodesic(user_location, ('latitude', 'longitude')).miles)
```

I get the error, "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'latitude'"

Is there a better way to annotate this so that I can sort by distance within the queryset?

Comment: The problem is that your `geodesic` function is in Python, whereas "annotate" is Django ORM magic that does the actual annotation at the database level and can thus only be used with ORM-provided functions (which internally translate to SQL). If you insist on using annotate, try find some Django-ORM-friendly way of doing the distance calculation ([this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219811/geodjango-how-to-calculate-distance-between-two-point) may get you started).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from Andre Borie, I decided to focus on sorting the queryset after-the-fact, and fixed it with this:

```
geocache_list_by_distance = sorted(geocache_list, key=operator.attrgetter('distance'))
    return geocache_list_by_distance
```